# Map numeric matplotlib axes into "string" variables in surface plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, surface

my issues is this: I have a table from which I want to obtain a 3d surface plot such as the one shown below in the code but the ticks on the x and y units need some "remapping", that is [0, 1, ...] must become ["apple", "orange", etc].

This is very important for me for visualization purposes (I can't switch to a categorical kind of chart because I would lose the "surface" feature).

In the code below, the `table` is a `pandas Dataframe` that is the "SQL like" representation of a 2D array plus the output values (as shown in almost all the matplolib case studies).

```
####################################################
         position  time_digitized  value
    0           0               0  0.636
    1           0               3  0.323
    2           0               1  0.783
    3           0               2  0.494
    4           0               4  0.452
    5           0               7  0.212
    6           0               5  0.465
    7           0               6  0.334
    8           0               8  0.182
    9           0              11  0.256
    10          0               9  0.244
####################################################

 from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d import Axes3D
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 from matplotlib import cm

 fig = plt.figure()
 ax = Axes3D(fig)
 surf = ax.plot_trisurf(
      table.loc[:, 'position'],
      table.loc[:, 'time_digitized'],
      table.loc[:, 'value'],
      cmap=cm.ocean,
      linewidth=0.1)
 fig.colorbar(surf, shrink=0.5, aspect=5)
 plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the xtickslabels with

```
ax.set_xticklabels(["orange",...])``
```

and for the y axis

```
ax.set_yticklabels(["apple",...])``
```

Hope this is what you are looking for.